# Error when reading user input and storing into array

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I have encounter an error when running this code. There will be a "program stop working" windows once it reaches the loop to scan for user input for the names ("scanf_s(%s", &nameptr[i]); ). 
Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 10
int findTarget(char *target, char nameptr[SIZE][80], int size);

int main()
    {
    char nameptr[SIZE][80];
    char t[40];
    int i, result, size;
    printf("Enter no. of names: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &size);
    printf("Enter %d names: ", size);


    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
            scanf_s("%s", &nameptr[i]); 

    printf("Enter target name: ");
    scanf_s("\n");
    gets(t);
    result = findTarget(t, nameptr, size);
    printf("findTarget(): %d\n", result);

    return 0;

    }

    int findTarget(char *target, char nameptr[SIZE][80], int size)
      {
      int i;
      for (i = 0; i<size; i++) {
      if (strcmp(nameptr[i], target) == 0)
        return i;
        }
    return -1;
      }
```

Comment: Avoid `gets` as it does not provide any protection against buffer overflows. Use `fgets` instead: `fgets(t, sizeof(t), stdin);`

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
scanf_s("%s", &nameptr[i]);
```

should be

```
scanf_s("%s", nameptr[i], sizeof(nameptr[i])); 
/* Or better */
scanf_s("%79s", nameptr[i], sizeof(nameptr[i]));
```

or

```
scanf_s("%s", nameptr[i], _countof(nameptr[i])); 
/* Or better */
scanf_s("%79s", nameptr[i], _countof(nameptr[i]));
```

because the `%s` in `scanf_s` expects a third argument denoting the maximum size of the string argument used. More information on this can be found at the [msdn documentation of `scanf_s`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! Its working now! May I know what is the use of the 3rd parameter for scanf_s and when does one need to use it?

Comment: @Jackelll The third parameter is to prevent [buffer overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow). It is needed when using `%s`, `%c` and `%[`. Otherwise, it is not required.